# Akamai request from Server unless ddos attack detected

Tags: akamai

Im looking for some help and no Akamai expert. Basically Im wondering if it is possible to implement Akamai in the following scenario:
1. Normal running request passes through akamai and only static assets such as css and js are cached, everything else is served direct from the server.
2. DDOS attack detected: Not sure if this is possible but the idea would be if akamai has a feature or api call to check if there has been a large scale ddos attack started, if so instead of passing the request to the app servers it reverts to a fully cached version of the site until the attack finishes.
Icing on the cake would be if we could set the threshold to what levels of attack to revert to, maybe based on a percentage over expected traffic levels?

Appreciate any sort of guidance.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes you can do this, either from Akamai config or by sending relevant headers from the origin (your site/API) telling Akamai not to cache certain files. Bear in mind that you'll still pay for traffic flowing through Akamai, even if they're not caching it, although if you have global users that want good performance you won't mind that cause the performance through their network is awesome.
2. They do indeed have a product that will protect you from ddos, how configurable it is I'm not sure but basically with Akamai everything is configurable if you've got the money to spend with them! Having said that, they wouldn't​ be serving anything to ddos requests of course, they'd be trying to determine where the attack is coming from and ignoring those requests so not sure what you're suggesting is what you'd actually want.

Comment: Hi sorry the idea is that during the attack all requests are served from cache. But if the request is scrubbed before it hits the app servers even for the pages you tell akamai not to cache, and it actually hits the app servers then actually that will probably be enough for my scenario. The only addition is that in an ideal world I could be selective with traffic, for example traffic in Asia is served fully from cache, but UK traffic hits app servers for anything other than static assets.

Comment: Well so bear in mind in an ideal world Akamai would be effectively ignoring all the bad traffic that was attacking your site and letting the good traffic through. Whether this good traffic was served from the Akamai cache or from your site would I guess be down to your general cache policies anyway, I'm not sure if it's possible to change those just when an attack is underway although as I said if you have the money to do custom solutions with Akamai it may well be.

Comment: I guess you've had a read of the various info online they have? Eg https://www.akamai.com/us/en/resources/ddos-protection.jsp, there's some info on there about treating geo locations differently in the event of an attack.

Comment: I have an idea that I might use azure traffic manager to route traffic first and then USD akamai if my server struggles thanks for your help

Comment: No problem, feel free to give me a tick or an up vote ;)